# How can I convert a Universal iOS app to a stand-alone iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, universal-binary

I started building a Universal app and it turned out the design doesn't work well with the iPad, so I've decided to make it a stand-alone iPhone app instead.  By that, I mean I'd like the app store to see my app as an iPhone app, not a Universal app.  I was just about to create a new project and move my existing iPhone code over to it and it's a ton of work because I had existing Core Data stores and other files that require some labor.

Is that the route I should take or is it easy to convert my existing Universal app to a stand alone iPhone app?  If it's easier to convert it, what do I need to do?

I was exploring the Build settings of my project (I don't know what most of them mean), but I see the "Targeted Device Family" setting.  Am I fortunate enough that I could simply set this to "iPhone" and that's the end of it?

Thanks in advance for your help!  I'm going to continue looking into this now...

**UPDATE:** I found that all I needed to do was set the "Targeted Device Family" build setting to "iPhone".  Seems to be working fine so far.

Comment: I can't fathom why this doesn't have more upvotes (the first one is mine).  Your question is important, clear, unique, well written, and not a duplicate.  695 people viewed this as of my comment, two starred it, and two upvoted the answer, but I'm the first to upvote the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that ends up setting the  UIDeviceFamily key in Info.plist, which should be what the App Store looks at. You might still have a bunch of iPad resources floating around, but I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: thanks, tc, i'm gonna make sure i get rid of those ipad resources.  so far, tho, it seems to work well.